# Obtain SAML assertion in exchange with OIDC token

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml, opensaml, pingfederate

We need to authentication SAML application (embedded browser in mobile app without any login prompt).
Mobile application is too integrated with same IDP using OIDC protocol

What can be the possible way to exchange OIDC token with SAML application for generating SAML assertion.

Comment: This is tagged with PingFederate. If you are actually using PF, then it can convert the incoming SAML assertion to an OIDC token set. Ping describes this functionality in this how-to doc: https://docs.pingidentity.com/r/en-us/solution-guides/htg_protect_pingaccess_resources_pingfed. You can replace the term "PingAccess" in that guide with your "Mobile Application".

Comment: @AndrewK. thanks Andrew. SAML assertion to OIDC token set is possible however, can we get SAML assertion from OIDC token in a mobile application? our mobile apps will be having OIDC session and on access certain link (another app) going via same IDP but SAML protocol. we want to have seamless authentication and login prompt.

Comment: I suggest updating your question to clearly describe the issue you are facing. Barring that, if you have PingFederate, you may want to consider reaching out to your account team and seeking guidance from them.